# prove that $a_{n}$ converges using Cauchy's convergence test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Check using Cauchy's convergence test if $a_{n}$ is convergent;
$$a_{1}=\frac{1}{3}$$  $$a_{n+1}=
\begin{cases}
a_{n}^2,  &\text{$a_{n}>\frac{1}{10}$} \\
2a_{n}, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

I need to show that $\forall m,n>\mathbb N$ Implies $\vert a_{m}-a_{n}\vert <\epsilon$
That's what I tried so far. 
$$
\begin{split}
\vert a_{m}-a_{n}\vert 
   &= \vert a_{m}-a_{m-1}+a_{m-1}-a_{m-2}+a_{m-2}+...-a_{n+1}+a_{n+1}-a_{n}\vert \\
   &\le \vert a_{m}-a_{m-1}\vert+\vert a_{m-1}-a_{m-2}\vert+...+\vert a_{n+1}-a_{n}\vert
\end{split}
$$
I don't know how to go from there and if this is even the right way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually not convergent. Try to prove:

[1] $a_n \gt \frac {1}{100}$ by induction on $n$.

[2] $|a_{n+1}-a_n| \gt \frac {1}{100}$ for every $n$.

[2] contradicts the Cauchy criterion (how?), thereby the sequence is divergent.